# React set an element with one className's min-height equal to the element with another className's min-height

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React Component with two `<div>` tags each with different `classNames` lets say: `className="firstClass"` and `className="secondClass"`.

How can I set the `min-height` value of `secondClass` to equal the `min-height` value of `firstClass`?

Comment: How do you set the `min-height` value of `firstClass`?

Comment: In the `componentDidMount()` function I set the `min-height'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't set the DOM directly. You need to read up on `setState` and `props`.

`setState` triggers a re-render, so whenever you do `this.setState({minHeight: newValueHere});` it will automatically update the render method with new values.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
            
    this.state = {
      minHeight: "600px"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="firstClass" style={{minHeight: this.state.minHeight}} />
        <div className="secondClass" style={{minHeight: this.state.minHeight}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```