# React Slick Slide Height Issue

Tags: css, reactjs, height, carousel, react-slick

I'm having trouble getting these React-Slick slider components to be the same height. They're both responsive divs and resize accordingly as the page size changes, but I would ideally want the div on the left to be the same height as the div on the right.

[image: picture that shows differing heights of divs in React-Slick slider]

I have my SimpleSlider defined with the below code snippet.

```
class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
  }
  render() {
    let settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      arrows: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2,
      initialSlide: 0,
      responsive: [...]
    };
    let Components = this.sliderObjects.components;

    return (
      <div>
        <h2> {this.sliderObjects.title} </h2>
        <Slider {...settings} >
        {
          Components.map((component,index)=>
           <div key={index}  >
            <SliderComponent key={index} {...component} />
            </div>
            )
        }
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And then my SliderComponent is defined as so

```
class SliderComponent extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='slick-slider-component'>
            <h3>{this.props.header}</h3>
            <p>{this.props.text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? It feels like it should be possible and not overwhelmingly difficult, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi, did you find a better solution to this problem instead of manually figuring out the height? I tried using flex but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know your maximum height, you can style your SliderComponent with some minHeight (or min-height in css). 
You can find some [input here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324813/react-set-an-element-with-one-classnames-min-height-equal-to-the-element-with-a)

if you don't know it:
hook in your componentWillMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const height = document.getElementById('slidercomponent-id').clientHeight;
    this.setState({ height });
  },
```

and set this height as your height in your div.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, and I've gotten it to almost work. For some reason the height being outputted when I log clientHeight is always off by a margin of like 50-80 pixels or so. I can fix this by adding on to the result outputted, but its not always off by a specific margin. Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Figured out if I add a setTimeout() around the block of code inside componentDidMount, it gives the accurate height

Answer (score 0):

I have added `centerPadding: '0px'`, after setting it worked for me